# generate list with guards and recursion

Tags: haskell

I am trying to generate a list of perfect squares between 2 values ***i*** and ***n*** using recursion and guards. I can achieve this with list comprehension (***i*** is not taken as an argument):

```
isPerfectSquare :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPerfectSquare n = sq * sq == n
    where sq = floor(sqrt(fromIntegral n :: Double))

squares :: Int -> [Int]
squares x = [y | y <- [1..x], isPerfectSquare y]
```

But I'm having trouble using recursion and guards for this.  I'm trying to implement this without using higher order functions or list comprehension. I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The usual trick is to generalize: instead of producing the squares in `1..x`, produce those in `a..b`. This means writing an auxiliary function that takes both `a` and `b` as arguments. You can then use `a`, do your job, and then recurse with `a+1`. How are the squares in `a..b` computed, knowing the recursive result of the squares in `a+1..b` ?

Comment: I've been struggling with this for a little and your comment helped a lot. Would you mind posting this as an answer so I can close my question? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual trick is to generalize the task: instead of producing the squares in `1..x`, produce those in `a..b`. This means writing an auxiliary function that takes both `a` and `b` as arguments.

Here's some skeleton code, to be adapted as needed.

```
squares :: Int -> [Int]
squares x = squaresFromTo 1 x

squaresFromTo :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
squaresFromTo a b
   | a > b     = ...  -- no squares here!
   | good a    = ...  -- keep a
   | otherwise = ...  -- discard a
   where
   otherSquares = squaresFrom (a+1) b
```

Now the question becomes: "how can we compute the squares in `a..b` knowing the recursive result `otherSquares` of the squares in `a+1..b` ?"